# How can i make my sprite move after mouse

Tags: c++, windows, sfml

i am trying to make my first game, but i am a completely newbie at SFML, and i wanted to make my sprite always move to mouse x position(without clicking any button) but i don't know how, i've tried many things and none of it worked + on internet, there are only tutorials how to make a "drag a sprite" code and for sfml 1.6 from 2013(i am using SFML 2.x).

Answer (score 0):

You should just update the sprite position to the mouse position every frame.

```cpp
while (window.isOpen()) // Your update loop
{
    [...]

    sprite.setposition(sf::Mouse::getPosition);

    [...]

    window.draw(sprite);
}
```